# In Git, how to push a branch to bare, without merging it to master?

Tags: git

I have master and a branch (b1) on my local machine.  Is it possible to push b1 to remote bare, without merging b1 to master?  And then pull from bare, into another repository?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
$ git push bare b1
```

Comment: git push origin b1, you mean?  push works, but when I pull it from another repo, say b2, it only shows me the files from master branch, not b1

Comment: you never mentioned the name of your remote - I thought you were talking about "a remote 'bare'"